# My firebase chat app is not coming in the messaging app list of choices to send

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, chat, public-key-encryption

I have made a firebase chat app for android platform. I have another have app to encrypt the text and send it using the other or third party apps by using intents. But when I click on the send button in the latter app, a list of apps appear to choose with which app I want to send the encrypted text, but in that list my firebase chat app is not coming as a choice. Can anyone help me with that ?
Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: show your manifest

Comment: manifest added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have your app listed in the menu, you need to have an activity with an intent filter to catch the action SEND. In your manifest you have only a launcher activity.

Comment: i am trying but its still not showing. Can you those lines of codes.